# What is the difference

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive

What is the difference between following sentences:

**Parents are being urged to keep an eye on their child.**

**Parents are urged to keep an eye on their child.**

Thanks.

Comment: The first says urging is being done (by someone); the second itself urges, in passive voice,

Answer (score 2):

---

- Parents are being urged [by teachers, for example as agent] to keep an eye on their children.
- Parents are urged [same as above] to keep an eye on their children.
  [children works better than child here]

Teachers **are urging parents** to keep an eye on their children. [are doing this now, at the moment].
Notice the passive transformation: Parents are being urged by teachers.

Teachers **urge** parents to keep an eye on their children. [as a general matter]

This is **present simple versus present progressive in a passive voice** without the agent. An agent is implied in passive voice. Present simple is for a generality and present progressive for something happening at the moment.

Another example:
I'm asking students to read this.
The students are being asked by me to read this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

Both of them have the literal descriptive meaning that someone is urging parents to keep an eye on their child.

Certain verbs like "urge", "encourage", "ask", "require", "prohibit", etc., can have the function of *actually doing the verb*.

So your sentences, if they appeared in a playground on a sign or if they were heard in an announcement over a loudspeaker, they would have the meaning: "Parents, keep an eye on your child." It's the same with or without passive voice. This means exactly the same thing:

> We urge parents to keep an eye on their child.

Again, on the surface this sentence appears to just be a description of what "we" do, but if it's on a sign, then it's actually *telling* parents what to do.

We usually use *simple present* for this function, so your second sentence is probably from a sign urging parents to watch their children, while your first sentence with *present continuous* is likely not from such a sign, so is more likely just a descriptive sentence about people urging parents to watch their children.